# Display some items inside a flexbox column as row

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have some flexbox item and it look like this https://jsfiddle.net/19ohjvuf/

This is the html

```
<div id="property">
              <div style="background-color:coral;"><img :src="item.property_image" width="200px" height="200px" /></div>
              <div class="grow-this" style="background-color:lightblue;"><h3 class="mt item-element">{{item.property_name}} {{item.property_star_rating}}</h3>
              <a href="" class="item-element">here street</a><a href="" class="item-element">Show On Map</a><a href="" class="item-element">2.7km from centre</a></div>
              <div style="background-color:lightgrey;">E</div>
              <div style="background-color:lightgreen;">Very Good</div>
            </div>
```

and this is the css

```
#property {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
}

#property div {
  flex-basis: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.mt{
margin-top:0px;
}
.grow-this{
flex-direction:column;
display: flex;
flex-grow: 1 !important;
}

.item-element{
margin-left:1% !important;
flex-flow: row;
}
```

i want the links inside `.grow-this` to arrange in a horizontal manner(row). I have tried changing `flex-direction` to be row

```
flex-direction:row;
```

and still they still stack as columns.

What can i do to make the links arrange themselves horizontally?

Comment: One way is to wrap the links in a `div` element and set `display: flex` on this wrapper `div` element.

Comment: @Yousaf beat me to it with his comment while I was writing my answer! See my second fiddle for the nested flex wrapper suggestion in action.

Comment: @maqam7 your answer points out an important point that `flex-direction` should be set on a flex container, not on flex items. OP used `flex-flow` property on flex items - from [MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-flow) _"The flex-flow CSS shorthand property specifies the direction of a flex container, as well as its wrapping behavior."_

Comment: Quick question though,lets say i want to add a badge element just after the h3, wouldnt that take the entire column width?

Comment: Having a hard time visualizing what you're after. Any chance you could mock up a quick image?

Comment: @maqam7 here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5axwkepb/   I am using bootstrap and i want an ordinary badge element after the title, instead it stretches full width

Comment: Try setting `align-items` property on `.grow-this`.

Comment: @Gandalf you could also do this: https://jsfiddle.net/u90mnq6g/ or this: https://jsfiddle.net/tjoncvmp/

Comment: Explain a little what you have done.

Comment: Real quick, are you trying to have the badge underneath the h3 or next to it? I had assumed the latter, but if you're going for underneath then I'd give you a different solution

Comment: I want the badge next to it.

Comment: Ok cool so as-is, all children of `.grow-this` will stack in a column. So anything inside that container that needs to arrange horizontally is in a nested container. The first fiddle has the spans wrapped in a div. No style applied to the div since spans are display: inline by default so unless they're controlled by a flex container to arrange vertically (as was the case before) then they'll be next to each other. The second fiddle works the same except instead of wrapping inside a div, I just nested one span inside the other. Make sense?

Comment: Yeah it does, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: I should point out that a flex container will only affect the layout of its immediate children. It doesn't cascade to all descendants (unlike, say, `text-align: center`). So one way to intentionally break a flex layout is to nest descendants in intermediate containers.

Comment: Cool, glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `flex-flow: row;` on `.item-element` you need to set the container those elements are children of to be `flex-direction: row`. That is the default value when an element is set to `display: flex;` so simply remove `flex-direction: column;` to make `.grow-this` display its children in a horizontal row:

https://jsfiddle.net/sm36ovxb/1/

Or, if you want `.grow-this` to be a column, but just have the links display next to each other in a nested row then you could wrap them in another `<div>` (or a `<ul>`) and set that to a flex row like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/xgpvmqo9/

Answer (score 0):

Try this: **flex-flow: row wrap;**

```
#property {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
```